# replace NAN or zero in one column with the content of the second column

Tags: perl

I want the contents of column 2 (when NAN/0)in file1.txt to be replaced by the content of column1:

This is my input file1.txt:

```
 file for parsing
 mnot   NAN
 PU1     0
 PU2     ets
 munt    tsu
 PU3    ttsm
 munt2    0
```

This is the required output file:

```
file for parsing
mnot   mnot
PU1    PU1
PU2    ets
munt   tsu
PU3    ttsm    
munt2  munt2
```

my code (below) is not giving the right output:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

open(IN, "<", "file1.txt") or die "Can't open file for reading:$!";

my $header = <IN>;
print OUT $header;


while (<IN>){
chomp;
my @sections = split(/\t/);
$sections[0] = 0;
$sections[1] = 0;

if (($sections[1] eq 'NAN') || ($sections[1] == 0)) {
    print OUT $sections[0], "\t", $sections[1], "\n";
    #print OUT "$sections[0]\n";
    }   
else {
    print OUT $sections[0], "\t", $sections[1], "\n";
    #print OUT "$sections[2]\n";
    }
 }
```

Please help!

Comment: You're printing the same thing in both the `if` and `else` blocks. How can that be right?

Comment: and you're assigning `0` to both the things you print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.` is current line number, so header is when `$. == 1`

`$"` is array separator when concatenating elements inside double quotes, ie. `"@sections"`

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open(my $IN, "<", "file1.txt") or die "Can't open file for reading:$!";
open(my $OUT, ">", "outfile.txt") or die "Can't open file for writing:$!";

local $" = "\t";
while (my $line = <$IN>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @sections = split(/\t/, $line);

  if ((!$sections[1] or $sections[1] eq 'NAN') and $. > 1) {
    $sections[1] = $sections[0];
    print $OUT "@sections\n";
    next;
  }
  print $OUT "$line\n";
}
```

Comment: Many thanks mpapec. It worked perfectly! I only had to make $IN and $OUT global (my $IN, my $OUT) and also modified "$sections[1] eq 'NAN' and $. > 1" to "$sections[1] eq 'NAN' || $sections[1] eq '0' and $. > 1" in order to replace occurences of 0 in column 2 with the content of column 1.

Comment: @user27976 tnx for comment